# Solve the following system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$$2x-y+z=5\\ x-z=3\\x+y-4z=4$$  I'm just learning how to solve systems of equations using an augmented matrix and elementary row operations. I got my solution to be Infinite solutions. Can someone confirm if my answer is correct? I don't want anyone to show work though because If I'm wrong I want to attempt the problem again. Thank you!

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Comment: It also depends on your field, or ring, over which you are considering your equations. For a linear code over $\mathbb{F}_q$ we have only finitely many solutions, of course.

Comment: It's correct...

Answer (score 2):

Summing the first and third,

> $$3x-3z=9,$$ which is the same as the second. So this is indeed a degenerate system.

Now leaving $z$ as a free parameter,

> $$x=z+3,y=2x+z-5=3z+1.$$